# How to exclude every process in Sysinternal's Process Monitor in the filter except for one process?

Tags: sysinternals, process-monitor

How to exclude every process in SysInternal's Process Monitor in the filter except for one process? Some kind of using a wildcard filter.

Comment: -1  it's remarkable to ask such a question, if you ever even attempted to use sysinternals process monitor then you'd see it has a foolproof include and exclude option. If you'd only tried Include, you'd see it does exactly what you want.  If you know te word "filter", and you have, it looks like you did something there, then spend another minute or two or much less after seeing the filter option,  it's really idiot proof to figure out yourself how to do what you want

Comment: @barlop I had an older version. When you add a process it gets added to the list of all the processes which are running. To exclude those, you have to exclude then one by one. It wasn't an efficient process.

Comment: that's a logical response from you, and i'll take your word for it, i've removed the -1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Click *Filter* (*Reset* if there is any) then apply this condition:

```
[Process Name] [is] [*process.exe*] [include]
```

Comment: You can also do this by process id.

Comment: And not only by process id. But using every other friggin column in there.

Comment: @surfasb +1  for your comment, yes, it's hard to see how somebody can fail to see how process monitor can do the behaviour he wants, just a minute or two of experimenting with the simple feature!

Comment: I think this should be [Process Name][is not][process.exe] [exclude] instead